# What is the difference between Windows Phone and Mobile tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just saw [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225215/how-are-the-points-awarded-in-asphalt-8-airborne-time-limited-events#225215) which uses [windows-phone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) and [windows-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile)

now to me both are the same because a mobile is a phone but that's just me (because i still use my smart phone as exactly that, a phone). so i am wondering in terms of usage what is the difference between these 2 tags? if they are just the same thing then i would like to suggest aliasing one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those tags refer to different platforms with similar names. [Windows Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) is an old operating system series that had its last release in 2010 (the same year as the last use of the tag). This is a different thing from the modern [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) operating systems or the upcoming [Windows 10 Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile) operating system.